# How to secure the server-to-server comunication between two endpoints?

Tags: server, tcp, ssl

Currently, I'm using these methods on HTTPS protocol:

- **SSL** to secure the communication between two endpoints
- **CheckSum** to generate a hash token that only the two endpoints can generate

Is there any way to detect that a specific request comes from the whitelisted server?

Comment: What kind of threats do you want to defend against? Security does not exist in a vacuum, but always serves some purpose. Depending on your threat model, various techniques such as encryption may be useful. As a primer, read up on [Confidentiality–Integrity–Availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Key_concepts)

Comment: Some way to detect that this request comes from a whitelisted server.

Comment: And what kind of communication are you securing? Are you developing your own protocol, or are you using an existing protocol such as HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, its a HTTPS communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HTTPS there are three relevant authentication mechanisms:

- Use TLS client certificates.
- Use HTTP Basic Access Authentication, i.e. the `Authorization` header.
  This is used by `https://user:password@example.com/` style URLs.
- Implement your own authentication on top of HTTPS.
  The client must first obtains a token (like a session cookie or JWT) from the server by posting some credentials.

Implementing your own auth or using HTTP Authentication generally requires a shared secret: the password. This requires that the (hashed) password has been stored on the server previously. Such plaintext authentication schemes also require an encrypted connection. Additionally, the server to which the client connects must be authenticated, which is generally done with a server certificate.

Instead of sharing the passwords which each server that a client connects to, a central authentication service can be used. This service issues a signed token when a client supplies the correct credentials. The authentication service's public key is known by all servers, so they can verify the authenticity of the token. The token is usually supplied through the HTTP `Authorization` header.

When using certificates for internal servers (either for client certificates or for server certificates) this requires you to run your own certificate authority (CA). The CA key is used to sign the public keys of all servers. The CA's public key must be imported into the trust chain of all servers and clients. This whole scheme is compromised once the CA private key is compromised. The `openssl` command line tool can be used to work as a CA, i.e. generate the CA key and sign certificates for other keys.

Client certificates are well supported in mature web clients, but are not commonly used as authentication for websites due to reasons that don't apply here. When done correctly, client certificates afford a very high level of security, and don't suffer from the same problems as pre-shared secret based authentication.